# How to link files directly from Github (raw.github.com)

Tags: github, github-pages, cdn

Are we allowed to link files directly from Github ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/username/project/master/style.css"/>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/username/project/master/script.js"></script>
```

I know this is allowed on Google Code. This way I don't have to worry about updating a local file.

Comment: You can see question analog with good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/how-to-link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-from-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Comment: Another link format (with double-slash) for raw content is "https://github.com/OWNER/REPO/raw/main//README.md"

Comment: This redirects to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OWNER/REPO/raw/main/README.md

Comment: You can directly use GitHub's raw content URL to serve files. Replace `blob` with `raw` in the file URL to get the raw content link. For example: `https://github.com/username/repository/raw/main/path/to/file.ext`

Answer (score 82):

<strike>The great service RawGit was already mentioned, but I'll throw another into the ring: [GitCDN.link](https://gitcdn.link)</strike>

Benefits:

- Lets you link to specific commits, as well as auto-get the latest (aka master)
- Incurs no damage from high traffic volumes; RawGit asks that it's dev.rawgit.com links be only used during development, where as GitCDN give you access to the latest version, without the danger of the servers exploding
- Give you the option of auto minifying your HTML, CSS and JavaScript, or serving it as written (https://min.gitcdn.link).
- Adds compression (GZip)
- Adds all the correct headers (Content-Type, cache-control, e-tag, etc)

Full disclosure, I'm a project maintainer at [GitCDN.link](Https://gitcdn.link)

This service has been shuttered due to Heroku's policy change to remove all free tiers.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for -- thanks a lot for the service. Suggestion: instead of requiring the raw URL, you should make it work with the regular URL as well (similar to rawgit).

Comment: @10basetom: Great suggestion! I'll add it to the roadmap!

Comment: @ShaneGadsby Thank you so much. Because of setting the correct headers it forces to download a file which was my desired behavior.

I had no other chance to force the download because GitHub even strip the `download` attribute when using HTML anchor elements.

Comment: If looking for LAST COMMIT CDN deployer, this is the best option.

Comment: I'm getting an Internal Server Error when I try this.

Comment: @ShaneGadsby does it still work? nothing happens when I paste a raw link into the input on the page.

Comment: website is down

Comment: Unfortunately, this was hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 38):

You can use external server `rawgithub.com`. Just remove a dot between words 'raw' and 'github' https://raw.github.com/.. => https://rawgithub.com/ and use it. [More info you find in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/how-to-link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-from-github)

However, according to the rawgithub website it will be shutting down at the end of October 2019.

Comment: There is also https://rawgit.com/ for serving raw files.

RawGit serves raw files directly from GitHub with proper Content-Type headers.

Comment: I believe that rawgithub.coma nd rawgit.com are the same service, that has been renamed :)

Comment: It appears that rawgit has issues with Chrome? https://snag.gy/VknHNQ.jpg

Comment: As of October 8, 2018, RawGit (aka rawgithub) is in a sunset phase. Look elsewhere.

Comment: It'd be good if we could delete all of the rawgit answers in this thread. There are 4 of them.

Answer (score 34):

Append `?raw=true` at the end of the file link.

---

**Example**

Original link:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/doc/source/_static/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png

Raw link:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/doc/source/_static/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png?raw=true

That will automatically redirect to:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/main/doc/source/_static/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: There are no Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers though.... so it's not very useful.

Comment: If you navigate to that url in a browser it re-directs to the `raw.githubusercontent` link now

Comment: @DouglasGaskell That might've been true then, but now, the header is present as: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: @theZ3r0CooL That's an advantage to me. Appending `?raw=true` is easier and less error prone than modifying the leading path (assuming this is all done manually).

Comment: At the current moment, appending `?raw=true` fails CORS but using the full `raw.githubusercontent.com` URL works.

Answer (score 21):

GitHub Pages: `https://yourusername.github.io/script.js`
GitHub repo raw files: `https://github.com/yourusername/yourusername.github.io/blob/master/script.js`

Use GitHub Pages, **DO NOT** use raw files.

Reason:
GitHub Pages are based on CDN, raw files are not. Accessing raw files will directly hit on GitHub servers and increase server load.

Comment: “*raw files are not*” Any source for that?

Comment: @Sista, Is it "are not" or "cannot"? Because the former can be fixed just with time.

Answer (score 16):

You can link directly to raw files, but it's best not to do it since the raw files always get sent with a plain/text header and can cause loading problems.

Comment: prevents loading in jsfiddle

Answer (score 15):

Add a branch your project using the name "gh-pages" and then you'll (shortly after branching) be able to use a direct URL such as https://username.github.io/project/master/style.css (using your URL, and assuming "style.css" is a file in the "master" folder in the root of your "project" repository...and that your Github account is "username").

Comment: the URL pattern may have changed since 2013: you no longer have to add "/master" to the URL, [https://username.github.io/project/file-path](https://username.github.io/project/file-path) is sufficient now

Answer (score 14):

You need carry out the following steps

1. Get the raw url of the file from github. Which is something like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/folder/example.css
2. Visit http://rawgit.com/. Paste the git url above in the input box. It will generate two url's, one for development and other for production purpose.
3. Copy any one of them and you are done.

The file will act as a CDN. You can also use gist urls.

Comment: "RawGit has reached the end of its useful life" - October 8, 2018

Answer (score 13):

Use jsdelivr.com

Copied directly from https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh:

load any GitHub release, commit, or branch
note: we recommend using npm for projects that support it

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/file

load jQuery v3.2.1

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js

use a version range instead of a specific version

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3.2/dist/jquery.min.js

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3/dist/jquery.min.js

omit the version completely to get the latest one

you should NOT use this in production

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

add ".min" to any JS/CSS file to get a minified version

if one doesn't exist, we'll generate it for you

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3.2.1/src/core.min.js

add / at the end to get a directory listing

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

After searching for this same functionality, I ended up writing my own `PHP` script to act as a proxy. The trouble I kept running into is even when you get the RAW version/link from `Github` and link to it in your own page, the header sent over was 'text/plain' and `Chrome` was not executing my `JavaScript` file from `Github`. I also didn't like the other links posted for using third party services because of the obvious security/tampering issues possible.

So using this script, I can pass over the RAW link from `Github`, have the script set the correct headers, and then output the file as if it were coming from my own server. This script can also be used with a secure application to pull in non-secure scripts without throwing `SSL` errors warning of "Non-secure links used".

**Linking:**

> <script src="proxy.php?link=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/repo/master/my_script.js"></script>

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
###################################################################################################################
# 
# This script can take two URL variables
# 
# "type"
#   OPTIONAL
#   STRING
#   Sets the type of file that is output
# 
# "link"
#   REQUIRED
#   STRING
#   The link to grab and output through this proxy script
# 
###################################################################################################################



# First we need to set the headers for the output file
# So check to see if the type is specified first and if so, then set according to what is being requested
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] != ''){
    switch($_GET['type']){
        case 'css':
            header('Content-Type: text/css');
            break;

        case 'js':
            header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
            break;

        case 'json':
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            break;

        case 'rss':
            header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
            break;

        case 'xml':
            header('Content-Type: text/xml');
            break;

        default:
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            break;
    }

# Otherwise, try and determine what file type should be output by the file extension from the link
}else{
    # See if we can find a file type in the link specified and set the headers accordingly

    # If css file extension is found, then set the headers to css format
    if(strstr($_GET['link'], '.css') != FALSE){
        header('Content-Type: text/css');

    # If javascript file extension is found, then set the headers to javascript format
    }elseif(strstr($_GET['link'], '.js') != FALSE){
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

    # If json file extension is found, then set the headers to json format
    }elseif(strstr($_GET['link'], '.json') != FALSE){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

    # If rss file extension is found, then set the headers to rss format
    }elseif(strstr($_GET['link'], '.rss') != FALSE){
        header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

    # If css xml extension is found, then set the headers to xml format
    }elseif(strstr($_GET['link'], '.xml') != FALSE){
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    # If we still haven't found a suitable file extension, then just set the headers to plain text format
    }else{
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    }
}

# Now get the contents of our page we're wanting
$contents = file_get_contents($_GET['link']);

# And finally, spit everything out
echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: LOL kinda hacky but its the solution I went with LOL... was wanting to use https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ BUT its not great for development when you're making a bunch of changes because of the CDN caching ... anyway thanks for the quick script!

Answer (score 0):

RawGit was a popular service for serving raw files directly from GitHub repositories. However, as multiple comments are mentioning, it has reached the end of its lifetime.

There are alternative options for serving raw files from GitHub repositories.

#### GitHub Raw Content URL

You can directly use GitHub's raw content URL to serve files. For example:

```
https://github.com/username/repository/raw/main/path/to/file.ext
```

As shown in the example, you can replace `blob` with `raw` in the file URL to get the raw content link.

#### GitHub Pages

GitHub Pages is a way to host static websites and assets, including images, directly from your GitHub repository. You can create a `gh-pages` branch or use the `docs` folder in your main branch to host your assets.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150245/6243352) and the [JSDelivr docs](https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh), here's a script to help generate a JSDeliver link. Paste in a GitHub file URL and it should give you the corresponding JSDeliver URL. Please leave a comment if you find any issues; I haven't tested it extensively.

```js
const createJSDelivrUrl = (ghUrl, {minify}) => {
  const jsDelivrPrefix = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh";
  const [username, repo, , version, ...path] = ghUrl
    .trim()
    .split("github.com/")[1]
    .split("/");
  const [file, ext] = path.at(-1).split(".");
  const finalPath = minify
    ? [...path.slice(0, -1), [file, "min", ext].join(".")]
    : path;
  return [
    jsDelivrPrefix,
    username,
    `${repo}@${version}`,
    ...finalPath,
  ].join("/");
};

const copyToClipboard = text => {
  const ta = document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(ta);
  ta.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(ta);
};

const handleChange = () => {
  try {
    const url = createJSDelivrUrl(ghUrl, {minify});
    out.innerHTML = `
      <button type="button">Copy</button>
      <a href="${url}">${url}</a>
    `;
    out.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
      copyToClipboard(url);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    out.textContent = "Invalid GitHub URL";
  }
};

const out = document.querySelector(".out");
let minify = false;
let ghUrl = "";
document
  .querySelector('input[name="min"]')
  .addEventListener("change", e => {
    minify = e.target.checked;
    handleChange();
  });

document
  .querySelector('input[name="gh-url"]')
  .addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    ghUrl = e.target.value.trim();
    
    if (ghUrl) {
      handleChange();
    } else {
      out.textContent = "";
    }
  });
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
[name="gh-url"] {width: 100%;}
body {max-width: 600px;}
button {padding-right: 0.2em;}
```

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
<h3>GitHub to JSDelivr converter</h3>
<p>
  Paste a GitHub file URL like <a href="https://github.com/ggorlen/prettybt/blob/master/js/pbt.js">https://github.com/ggorlen/prettybt/blob/master/js/pbt.js</a> to generate a JSDeliver URL.
</p>
<input name="gh-url" placeholder="GH file URL">
<label>
  Minify <input name="min" type="checkbox">
</label>
<p class="out"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could publish (1) these js/css files in GitHub Pages, then you can reference (2) these files...

(1) Publish
Original source: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

You have to make your repo public or upgrade to a paid plan.

So you can go to "Settings / Code Automation / Pages". Then in "Build and Deployment" choose Source "Deploy from a branch" and after that select the branch name and folder.

You wait some minutes until deploy starts. In the end you can view the link for your project on "github.io" like this "https://username.github.io/projectname". From this moment you can try get your file, for example typing the url: https://username.github.io/projectname/js/script.js

(2) Reference the files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://username.github.io/projectname/css/style.css"/>
<script src="https://username.github.io/projectname/js/script.js"></script>
```

(END)

Don't use raw links.

Answer (score -1):

If your webserver has active allow_url_include, GitHub serving the files as raw plain/text is not a problem since you can include the file first in a PHP script and modify its Headers to the proper MIME type.