# Datatables and bootstrap tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am adding Datatables to my Rails app.  I have it working for the most part but I am stuck on a CSS / jQuery issue.  I have a row cell defined as follows:

```
content_tag(:abbr, "#{record.od} mm", data: { container: 'body', toggle: 'tooltip', placement: 'bottom', html: 'true' }, title: 'test' )
```

which renders:

```
<abbr data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="test">88.9 mm</abbr>
```

In a non-datatable table the bootstrap tooltip works fine but fails on the datatable.  From experience I gather it's because the datatable is rendered after the body completes etc.

After some digging I tried this:

```
$ ->
  $('#table').dataTable
    ajax: 
      url: myurl
    processing: true
    serverSide: false
    responsive: true
    'fnCreatedCell': (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) ->
      $(nTd "abbr").tooltip()
```

This almost works... almost because I get a tooltip but I am guessing it's a datatable tooltip vs the bootstrap tooltip:

[image]
[image]

Forget the tooltip content - the formatting etc. is the issue.  The non-bootstrap tooltip also takes way longer to fade in.

Is there perhaps an easy fix here?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I'd perhaps add a class to the tooltip (such as `tooltip`) and then call the tooltip function in the draw callback. I little like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189856/datatables-with-eonasdan-datepicker-doesnt-work/39191075#39191075

Comment: Try using delagation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: $('body').tooltip selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' did the trick.  If you add this as an actual answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`selector` option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options):

```
$('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
```

This works for popovers too.

Answer (score 24):

You need to use `drawCallback` to initialize tooltips every time DataTables redraws the table.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {  
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {

$('[data-toggle="tooltip1"]').tooltip();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip2"]').tooltip();

// add as many tooltips you want

},
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I just used run `.tooltip()` on `[data-toggle="tooltip"]` once (as opposed to creating many toggles for each tooltip and it seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: I changed responsive = false, xscroll=true, but it is blinking continuously why I don't know. please tell me

Answer (score 3):

only this worked for me

```
drawCallback: function () {
     $('body').tooltip({ selector: '[data-tooltip="tooltip"]' });
},
```