# JSON schema reference ($ref) not expanded when using raml2html

Tags: json, jsonschema, raml

I'm using [raml2html](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) to generate HTML pages from JSON schemas. But the schema reference ($ref) used in my JSON schema is not expanded as expected and I'm not sure why.

I've followed instructions from [raml-jsonschema-expander](https://github.com/br-adam-newman/raml-jsonschema-expander), the tool used by raml2html to expand references.

My referencing JSON schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://raw.github.com/path/to/balances.json#",
  ...
  ...
      "$ref": "balance.json#"
  ...
```

My referenced JSON schema, `balance.json`, which is hosted on GitHub:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://raw.github.com/path/to/balance.json#",
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the way GitHub serves contents, as discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779197/linking-files-directly-from-github).

I ended up setting up a `gh-pages` branch in that repository and stored the JSON schema files in that branch. Now the referenced schemas are properly fetched and rendered.