# Google Maps not working in Firefox and Safari

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, firefox, safari

I have an issue on a Wordpress website in which the Google Maps doesn't load on Firefox and Safari specifically. The map shows blank and a message Loading map...that never ends on those 2 browsers.

This curious message in yellow is displayed on the browser on Google Chrome:

```
jquery.min.js?ver=1.11.1:4 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label/blob/gh-pages/src/maplabel.js?_=XXXXXXXXXX with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

and in Firefox it displays the following message also as a yellow alert:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label/blob/gh-pages/src/maplabel.js?_=XXXXXXXXX”.
```

Any clue on what it only works in Chrome and not in Firefox and Safari? Any clue how to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the error, your [CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) does not allow you to load scripts from github.com domain.

You can :

- Edit your `content-security-policy` headers to allow `https://github.com` loading. You can do it from your Apache/Nginx settings, or from PHP (if you use it) but I prefer handling those headers from web-server config.

  - CSP can also be managed using [header meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Exemple_1)
  - As you're directly serving from Github, you may need to change the [default-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) as content-type is `text/html`. I don't know if the [script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) will handle it.
- Download and upload the script to your server. Like this, it'll be loaded from the same domain, and should not throw CSP error.

Also:

- Using files directly from GitHub is not the best idea. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779197/how-to-link-files-directly-from-github-raw-github-com) and from your console error `with MIME type text/html`, Github serve your JS file as `text/html` instead of `application/javascript`.
- It would be better to use a proper CDN (if a CDN serving your file exist), or store the file on your server.

Comment: Can i add that individualy to this website though the .htaccess? If so, how does that script would look like?

Comment: Actually it only works for Chrome and not for other browsers

Comment: You could try `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://github.com"
</IfModule>`. Use `script-src` if you have the correct content type.